# Segmentation Fault when linking assembly program with `ld`

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault

I have some Assembly codes as below: (max.s file)

```
.section .data
d1: .double 12.5
d2: .double 6.5

formatstr: .asciz "Max value is: %lf\n"

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    movsd d1,%xmm0
    movsd d2,%xmm1
    ucomisd %xmm1,%xmm0
    ja endif
then:
    movsd %xmm1,%xmm0
endif:
    mov $formatstr,%edi
    mov $1,%eax
    call printf
    call exit
```

When I compiled it:

```
as max.s -o max.o
ld -lc -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o max max.o
```

Then no error occurred.

But when I ran this file by `./max` then this following error occurred: Segmentation fault

Comment: This is a program for 64-bit Linux. Because you've got no error from `ld` I guess you tried to build it on a 32-bit system.

Comment: Yes. That code is belong to my teacher. He compiled it on class and of course it ran. I went home and reused that code and did not work, cause i dont think 32bit different from 64bit

Comment: There are substantial differences between 32bit and 64bit. In your case you stumbled on the calling conventions: [cdecl (32bit - your system )](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) vs. [System_V_AMD64 (64bit - teacher's system)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your program uses `libc` functions: `printf` and `exit` (in addition to `ld-linux`), without having properly initialized `libc`.

That initialization normally happens in `_start`, provided by `libc` itself in `crt0.o`.

You also mix `ix86` and `x86_64` calling conventions, and call `printf` incorrectly (this is likely the immediate cause of the crash). In 32-bit mode (which you are apparently using), parameters are passed on stack, not in registers.

As Jeff Bell, answered, either rename your `_start` to `main` and use `gcc` instead of `ld` to link your program (after fixing your source to use correct calling convention), or get rid of `libc` dependencies by implementing `printf` and `exit` yourself and not linking with `ld-linux` and `-lc`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix my source to use correct calling convention ?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling exit(3) without passing a return value.  The normal way to exit _start from assembler is with a sys_exit system call.

Personally I would use **main** instead of **_start**.  That way you'll get all of the initialization and cleanup such as flushing the i/o and calling the on_exit code that comes for free with exit(3).

(The only reason you might use your own _start is if you wanted to avoid libc in order to have a smaller executable.  There is a discussion of how to do this here https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/hello_from_a_libc_free ).

Comment: Calling `exit` without passing a value would cause random garbage for exit code, but not a `SIGSEGV`. The rest of your advice is good though.